# single tab bar on chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, developer-tools, usability

recent chrome/chromium versions separate the dev tools into two bars.

the top one with Elements, Network, Sources, etc

and the bottom one with Console, Emulation, Rendering.

This is nothing but a waste of space for me. Specially when i'm having to use a laptop with a 720p resolution.

Is there any way to go back to the sane default of one tab bar? I could not find anything on the settings, so i am hopping that someone knows something hidden or on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the top right, click on the three dots and select "Hide console". 
Alternatively press the `esc` key.

[image: screenshot of the hide console buttion]